# Remove string + characters using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm quite new to regex and I was wondering if there is a way of doing this in a one line regex expression

```js
let error = '{"error":"invalid email address"}'
document.write("<p>old: <b>",error,"</b></p>")
error = error.replace(/["\{\}:]/g,'')//this
error = error.replace(/error/g,"")//and this in one line
document.write("<p>new: <b>",error,"</b></p>")
```

```css
p{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: you can chain replaces (i.e. `.replace().replace()`), if that's what you mean? or do you mean in one regex?

Comment: I mean with the regex but thanks anyway for the response i'll try it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group, created with `()`, and put the result of that group into the replace statement with `$1` where you can replace `1` with the number of the capture group:

```
error = error.replace(/{"error":"(invalid email address)"}/g, '$1')
```

```js
let error = '{"error":"invalid email address"}'
document.write(`<p>old:<b> ${error}</b></p>`)
error = error.replace(/{"error":"(invalid email address)"}/g, '$1')
document.write("<p>new: <b>",error,"</b></p>")
```

```css
p{
display: block;
}
```

If the string "invalid email address" can change, then you'll want to capture any string except `"`, which you can do with:

```
error = error.replace(/{"error":"([^"]+)"}/g, '$1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Matt Ellen but does this still work if invalid email address is a dynamic value?

Comment: I have updated the answer for that circumstance. Although if the error message *can* include `"` then there will be problems and you'd need some kind of lookbehind construction